# ¿Qué puedo usar para simular un "Procedimiento almacenado" en PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado hecho en **SQL SERVER** pero necesito replicarlo en **PostgreSQL** sin embargo no encuentro nada relacionado con procedimientos almacenados.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PA_ALTA_CLIENTE]
    (
        @ID_RESPONSABLE INT,
        @ID_MEMBRESIA INT,
        @NOMBRE VARCHAR (30),
        @APELLIDO_P VARCHAR (30),
        @APELLIDO_M VARCHAR (30),
        @FECHA_NAC DATE,
        @CALLE VARCHAR (50),
        @NUMERO INT,
        @COLONIA VARCHAR (30),
        @CODIGO_P CHAR(5),
        @MUNICIPIO VARCHAR (50),
        @LOCALIDAD VARCHAR (50),
        @ESTADO VARCHAR (50),
        @STATUS BIT OUTPUT,
        @MENSAJE VARCHAR (100) OUTPUT
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE ID_USUARIO = @ID_RESPONSABLE)
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @ID_CLIENTE INT
                    SET @ID_CLIENTE = (SELECT ID_MEMBRESIA FROM CLIENTES WHERE
                    @NOMBRE = NOMBRE AND
                    @APELLIDO_P = APELLIDO_P AND
                    @APELLIDO_M = APELLIDO_M AND
                    @FECHA_NAC = FECHA_NAC
                    )

                    IF @ID_CLIENTE IS NULL
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO CLIENTES
                            VALUES (@ID_MEMBRESIA,@NOMBRE,@APELLIDO_P,@APELLIDO_M,
                            @FECHA_NAC,@CALLE,@NUMERO,@COLONIA,@CODIGO_P,@MUNICIPIO,@LOCALIDAD,@ESTADO,'SI')

                            INSERT INTO BITACORA VALUES 
                            (@ID_RESPONSABLE, 'CLIENTES',('Dio de alta un nuevo cliente: '+
                            @NOMBRE +' '+@APELLIDO_P+' '+@APELLIDO_M),
                            GETDATE())

                            SET @STATUS = 'true'
                            SET @MENSAJE = 'Se ha registrado un nuevo cliente satisfactoriamente'
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @MENSAJE = 'Este cliente ya existe en la base de datos'
                            PRINT @MENSAJE
                            SET @STATUS ='false'
                        END
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN 
                    SET @MENSAJE = 'Usuario denegado. Operaciòn inclompleta'
                    PRINT @MENSAJE
                    SET @STATUS ='false'
                END
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @STATUS = 'false'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: [Aqui](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/stored_procedures_functions) hay documentacion de procedimientos almacenados en PostgreSQL.

Comment: ah es que en PostgreSQL usas funciones

Comment: @Alan Rodriguez no soporta procedimientos almacenados tendrias que usar funciones

Comment: Ok, ok, y por ejemplo se puede replicar eso mismo con funciones

Answer (score 2):

Postgresql no soporta procedimientos (**procedures**), lo que sí podrías hacer es simular su funcionalidad creando una función que no necesite retornar valores.

**Ejemplo:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(id int, comment text) RETURNS void AS $$
    DECLARE
        test_time timestamp := now();
    BEGIN
        /*
        * codificar aquí
        */
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Al usar **RETURNS void** en la declarativa, la función no necesita retornar valores y por ende su comportamiento se asemeja a la de un procedimiento.

Comment: Entonces, ¿Podria dejar el "RETURN void AS $$ " asi tal cual lo dejaste y solo poner mi codigo en el apartado de begin?

Comment: Tenes que adaptar el código a postgresql algunas sintaxis puede que no te funcione si copias directamente.